# Lunar new year for php

Tags: php, internationalization

Just curious how would I convert from Gregorian calendar dates to the lunar calendar dates used in East Asia?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a trivial algorithm, since both calendars have complicated rules to account for the non-integral number of days in a lunar/solar orbital period and the non-integral number of lunar orbital periods in a solar period.  This might help: http://www.mandarintools.com/calconv_old.html

Note that almost everyone in East Asia who uses the Internet is familiar with the Gregorian calendar.  In fact, I think very few would know the precise year, month, and day in the lunar calendar.